# Stereochemistry + isomer check

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stereochemistry

We start with compound M:

[image]

[Please imagine green bonds as dotted bonds going into the plane]

From compound M, we are told that the 3 membered ring is opened u using sodium azide yielding a mix of isomers N and O.

I drew the following:

[image]

and

[image]

**[Again, please imagine the green bonds as dotted bonds and the blue
bonds as wedge bonds]**

Given are the following two molecules:

[image]

Are my solutions the same as the ones given? If they aren't, where did I go wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: Your solutions are not the same. You have not considered atttack by azide on the epoxide next to the ether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for both products, you have not given the **O atom** in the carbonyl position. In organic chemistry, we assume that there is a **C atom if no atom is mentioned specifically**. Now for this reaction, the carbonyl group will be there as it is.

Now we can consider the reaction. The **epoxide is away from the plane, i.e. below the plane**. For the steric reason, it is more feasible for azide to **attack from the upper side of the plane**. Now again, azide can attack both **C centre of the 3-membered epoxide ring**. In that case, we'll be having **two different products**. But in both cases, we will have the **azide group on the above of the plane** and **O atom in the below of the page**.

Now if I assume that you have **mistakenly skipped the O atom** in your both products, then `your first molecule matches with the first answer given below`. But  `the second answer given by you is not correct and doesn't match with the second answer`. You can have the green and blue coloured bond in the same place and then you have to **alternate the position of OH group and azide group**. Then that will match the answer given below and the answer will be correct.

Comment: Thanks @aritaroy24 - you are right - I missed out the carbonyl oxygen by mistake

Comment: @aritaroy24 - I also now understand that the azide will attack from the upper side and so the N3 part will always be above the plane. Is there any where I can find out more about this type of attack for olympiad purposes? (I am a high school student in the UK - A level, if that helps)

Comment: Google is your friend! Search "nucleophilic opening of epoxides" and you will get hits like this: https://www.khanacademy.org/science/organic-chemistry/alcohols-ethers-epoxides-sulfides/ring-opening-reactions-epoxides/v/ring-opening-reactions-of-epoxides-strong-nucleophiles

Comment: @Waylander is correct. It's just a basic type of reaction. You can find it on google by just typing the words mentioned above.